# checking button image in android

Tags: android, image, button

In my android application i'm checking image of button.and then changing it.
how can i do this?

code-

```
Drawable a;
a=b1.getBackground();
int i=R.drawable.happy;
// b1 is button
if(a==R.drawable.happy)
 b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whoa);
else
 b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
```

Comment: Is this showing any error??

Comment: yes. a is drawabale type and R.drawable.happy in if condition is int

Comment: you might try `getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.happy).equals(a)`. The way you have it, an `int` will never equal a `Drawable`

Comment: Are you getting any value in a? Or is there any error in logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Drawable a = b1.getDrawable();
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy);
// b1 is button
if(image.equals(a))
 b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whoa);
else
 b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
```